# airflow tells me to delete ~/airflow/airflow.cfg. But when I do, it keep getting re-created

Tags: airflow

```
AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/my/airflow_home
```

I get this warning ...

```
>airflow trigger_dag python_dag3
/Users/alexryan/miniconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:627: DeprecationWarning: You have two airflow.cfg files: /Users/alexryan/airflow/airflow.cfg and /path/to/my/airflow_home/airflow.cfg. Airflow used to look at ~/airflow/airflow.cfg, even when AIRFLOW_HOME was set to a different value. Airflow will now only read /path/to/my/airflow_home/airflow.cfg, and you should remove the other file
```

I complied and deleted ~/airflow/airflow.cfg, but it keeps coming back.

Is there some way to tell airflow to stop re-creating this?

Running on macOS Mojave

```
>pip freeze | grep air
apache-airflow==1.10.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a systemd service for airflow server?

I think the ~/airflow folder is recreated again and again because you run webserver as daemon mode (maybe launchctl? I am not familiar with macOS)

You should figure out how to pass the enviroment variables to the daemon process. On Linux platform, when daemon configuration is created, "Environment=AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/my/airflow_home" is neccessary.

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
Environment="AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/my/airflow_home"
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow webserver
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```